# Can Scala traits have vars, not just vals?

Tags: scala, var, traits

I'm looking at Scala traits, but have yet to program in it, making this a hypothetical question.

All of the examples that I've seen so far have concrete or abstract fields that only use `val` in their declaration instead of `var`.  Can fields declared with `var` be used in Scala traits?

TIA,
Matthew

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: vars should be avoided for many reasons in scala, initially it's difficult to transition to this thinking - but rewarding when your code is side-effect free and threadsafe by design.

Answer (score 3):

If you *try* it you'll see it works:

```
scala> trait TestTrait {
     | var x = 1
     | }
defined trait TestTrait

scala> val t = new TestTrait { }
t: TestTrait = $anon$1@4c32060c

scala> t.x = 2
t.x: Int = 2

scala> t.x
res0: Int = 2
```

If you read into how `var` and `val` are compiled in Scala this makes sense. A `val` is a private field with an auto-generated *getter* method, and the only difference for a `var` is that is has a setter as well.