# How can I scala-ify this block:

Tags: scala

Scala newbie here...
How can I scalify this block:

```
if(sess != null) {
  sess.any = params.get("any").getOrElse("")
  sess.name = params.get("name").getOrElse("")
  sess.entity = params.get("entity").getOrElse("")
  sess.tin = params.get("tin").getOrElse("")
  sess.tintype = params.get("tintype").getOrElse("")
  sess.bdate = params.get("bdate").getOrElse("")
  sess.addr = params.get("addr").getOrElse("")
  sess.city = params.get("city").getOrElse("")
  sess.state = params.get("state").getOrElse("")
  sess.zip = params.get("zip").getOrElse("")
}
```

sess is just an instance of a case class.

Comment: Maybe you'll get an answer here, but you might have better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally wouldn't make `sess` mutable, but the simplest solution here is to just pull out the removable common code.  You can't in general look up and set fields by name, so the `sess.x =` part has to stay, and case classes don't have strings that match their field names, so the `"x"` has to stay.  So that leaves

```
if (sess != null) {
  def get(s: String) = params.get(s).getOrElse("")
  sess.any = get("any")
  /* ... */
  sess.zip = get("zip")
}
```

Still a lot of boilerplate, but probably better than messing around with reflection, and definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might want to consider a **key-value map** wrapped into a simple class.

This way you can write your custom methods for adding/removing/checking elements which would resemble accessing a case class.

If you want type safety for the keys, the keys of the map could be objects extending a common trait like:

```
trait MyKey
object AnyKey extends MyKey
object NameKey extends MyKey
```

`MyKey` can also have a String [field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539829/can-scala-traits-have-vars-not-just-vals) that could be used when calling the params.get() method when you are populating the **map**.

Then you could put all the keys into a `List[MyKey]` and do a foreach on the list to populate your map.

If you need to pattern match on this wrapper class then you can use [extractors](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_extractors.htm).

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [Shapeless 2.0.0](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3a-shapeless-2.0.0). First assume a shortened version of `sess`,

```
case class sess(val any: String, val name: String, val entity: String)
```

and a listing of its member names (parameters in this question),

```
val args = List("any", "name", "entity")
```

or alternatively for example

```
val args = "any,name,entity".split(",").toList
```

Define a `get` method for fetching possible parameter values, as already suggested,

```
implicit class parameterGetter( val parameters: Map[String,String]) extends AnyVal {
  def get(s: String) = parameters.get(s).getOrElse("")
}
```

under the assumption that `params` in the question is a `Map[String,String]`.

Then fetch a value for each argument

```
val argsVals = args.map { a => params.get(a).get }
```

and tuple the result,

```
import shapeless._
import HList._
import syntax.std.traversable._

// Especially useful if case class includes different types
val argsH = argsVals.toHList[String::String::String::HNil]
val argsTupled = argsH.get.tupled
```

For a case class such as

```
case class sees2(val city: String, val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

the typing in `toHList` would be `String::Int::Int::HNil` instead.

Last, create an instance of `sess`,

```
val mySess = sess.tupled(argsTupled)
```

Test this by fetching values from `mySess`

```
mySess.any
mySess.name
mySess.entity
```